# trouble to exec more than 2 pipes in a linux shell simulator (c)

Tags: c, pipe, exec

I am trying to make a linux shell simulator, but Im having trouble when the input is a command with more than 2 pipes. Here is my code:

```
int Executa_Fork(char ***comando,int npipe){
    pid_t pid;
    int status,i,j;
    int **pipefd;
    
    pipefd = malloc(sizeof(int *)*(npipe));
    
    for(i = 0;i < npipe;i++){
        pipefd[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    }
    
    for(i = 0;i <= npipe;i++){
        if(npipe != i){
            if (pipe(pipefd[i]) < 0) { 
                perror("pipe"); 
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
                } 
        
        }
        
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        if(pid == 0){ //processo filho
            printf("filho");
            if(i == 0){
                dup2(pipefd[i][1], 1);

                close(pipefd[i][0]);
                close(pipefd[i][1]);
            }else if(i != npipe){   
                dup2(pipefd[i-1][0], 0);

                dup2(pipefd[i][1], 1);

                close(pipefd[i][0]);
                close(pipefd[i][1]);
                close(pipefd[i-1][0]);
                close(pipefd[i-1][1]);

            }else{
                dup2(pipefd[i-1][0], 0);

                close(pipefd[i-1][0]);
                close(pipefd[i-1][1]);
            }
            printf("%s %s\n", comando[i][0], comando[i][1]);
            if(execv(comando[i][0],comando[i]) == -1){
                perror("exec");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;

}
```

npipe is the pipe number of command inputed, and comando stores the commands with the comando[command index] being a command to be exec. If someone could help me find a way to execute more than 2 pipes commands I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trouble is that if you have a pipeline such as:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | cmd4
```

(connected by pipes P1, P2, P3), then by the time you're processing `cmd3`, the parent process has P1, P2 and P3 open, and so does the child.  And your child code carefully closes P2 and P3, but not P1 — and you need to close P1 too.  And you need to review what the parent process does with the pipes; it should probably close them too.